# I want to make a maths quiz on vb.net that uses bracket questions

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, math, coding-style, vb.net-2010

So I've used visual basics (vb.net) for a bit now and understand some stuff. Right now I want to make a maths quiz that when I click a button it takes me to a new form and starts the quiz. When the quiz starts I want it so it gives the user random numbers and the user needs to answer it in a textbox and if correct it moves on to the next question (Basic, I should be able to do). IMPORTANT - my question is, there's a maths rule called BODMAS (Bracket.Order.Division.Multiply.Add.Subtract) and I want to add this rule into my coding instead of doing regular simple maths...

EXAMPLE question is 2 x (2+3) - 1 = ?

1. 2 x 5 - 1 = ?
2. 10 - 1 = ?
3. 9 = 9
   *person writes answer to textbox and moves to next similar question*

This is my first time using this but I wanted to write in-depth so people can understand. Please help me if you find a video explaining what I'm looking for or if someone has a file with a similar code I could download would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Basically,you need to determine the range of numbers you use, and then match them randomly among '*', '/', '+', '-'. Then randomly insert brackets into it.

```
Private codeStr As String
Private Function GenerateMathsQuiz() As String
    Dim r As Random = New Random()
    Dim builder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    'The maximum number of operations is five, and you can increase the number [5] to increase the difficulty
    Dim numOfOperand As Integer = r.[Next](1, 5)
    Dim numofBrackets As Integer = r.[Next](0, 2)
    Dim randomNumber As Integer

    For i As Integer = 0 To numOfOperand - 1
        'All numbers will be random between 1 and 10
        randomNumber = r.[Next](1, 10)
        builder.Append(randomNumber)
        Dim randomOperand As Integer = r.[Next](1, 4)
        Dim operand As String = Nothing

        Select Case randomOperand
            Case 1
                operand = "+"
            Case 2
                operand = "-"
            Case 3
                operand = "*"
            Case 4
                operand = "/"
        End Select

        builder.Append(operand)
    Next

    randomNumber = r.[Next](1, 10)
    builder.Append(randomNumber)

    If numofBrackets = 1 Then
        codeStr = InsertBrackets(builder.ToString())
    Else
        codeStr = builder.ToString()
    End If

    Return codeStr
End Function
Public Function InsertBrackets(ByVal source As String) As String
    Dim rx As Regex = New Regex("\d+", RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = rx.Matches(source)
    Dim count As Integer = matches.Count
    Dim r As Random = New Random()
    Dim numIndexFirst As Integer = r.[Next](0, count - 2)
    Dim numIndexLast As Integer = r.[Next](1, count - 1)

    While numIndexFirst >= numIndexLast
        numIndexLast = r.[Next](1, count - 1)
    End While

    Dim result As String = source.Insert(matches(numIndexFirst).Index, "(")
    result = result.Insert(matches(numIndexLast).Index + matches(numIndexLast).Length + 1, ")")
    Return result
End Function
```

When you finish this, you will get a math quiz, then you need to know how to compile and run code at runtime.

```
Private Function GetResult(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder("")
    sb.Append("Namespace calculator" & vbCrLf)
    sb.Append("Class calculate " & vbCrLf)
    sb.Append("Public Function Main() As Integer " & vbCrLf)
    sb.Append("Return " & str & vbCrLf)
    sb.Append("End Function " & vbCrLf)
    sb.Append("End Class " & vbCrLf)
    sb.Append("End Namespace" & vbCrLf)
    Dim CompilerParams As CompilerParameters = New CompilerParameters()
    CompilerParams.GenerateInMemory = True
    CompilerParams.TreatWarningsAsErrors = False
    CompilerParams.GenerateExecutable = False
    CompilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/optimize"
    Dim references As String() = {"System.dll"}
    CompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(references)
    Dim provider As VBCodeProvider = New VBCodeProvider()
    Dim compile As CompilerResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParams, sb.ToString())

    If compile.Errors.HasErrors Then
        Dim text As String = "Compile error: "

        For Each ce As CompilerError In compile.Errors
            text += "rn" & ce.ToString()
        Next

        Throw New Exception(text)
    End If

    Dim Instance = compile.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("calculator.calculate")
    Dim type = Instance.GetType
    Dim methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Main")
    Return methodInfo.Invoke(Instance, Nothing).ToString()

End Function
```

Finally, you can use these methods like:

```
Private Sub GetMathQuizBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetMathQuizBtn.Click
    Label1.Text = GenerateMathsQuiz()
End Sub
Private Sub ResultBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResultBtn.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = GetResult(Label1.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("bingo!")
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        Label1.Text = GenerateMathsQuiz()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("result is wrong")
    End If
End Sub
```

Result:
[image]